# how to open tex.m in matlab folder

Tags: matlab

I would like to open `tex.m` that is located inside this folder

`C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\mcr\toolbox\matlab\graphics`

However, it shows me weird characters

[image]

I've opened it with notepad++ but with the same problem. Is the file protected? With another computer but not the same version of Maltab, I can open the file with no problems. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Check your file protections and run Matlab in Admin mode. I think it will solve your problem. If problem still occurs, try to change your working directory to folder on desktop or anywhere which is not under program files.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference.  I just tried it on Mac OS where I have full permissions and I get it to be encrypted like the OP as well.

Comment: It seems that same file is located in a different folder, therefore I can open it with no problem. I have no idea what are these files and why they are encrypted. The good file is located in `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\matlab\graphics`

Comment: May be it is all about your code. If your code writes a file with same name and it is interrupted for some reason during write operations, then you can get these kind of errors.